# Creating a day schedule

Tags: java

I just need some help with one part of my code.  I have 3 classes, Activity, DaySchedule, and DayScheduleFrontEnd.  In the DaySchedule Class a have a method called addActivity:

```
public void AddActivity(Activity aActivity)
{
    //Check if activity array is full
    if(activities[activities.length-1] != null)
    {
        System.out.println("The activities database is full");
        return;
    }
    //Find the first empty space
    for(int i=0;i<activities.length;i++)
    {
        if(activities[i] == null)
        {
            activities[i] = aActivity;
            break;
        }
    }
    this.SortActivitiesByTime();
}
```

What I need help on is that an activity cannot conflict with another one.  An activity conflicts if the start and the end of one activity cannot fall at the same time as another.  If this were to occur the user should be notified and the activity is not added.  Also this method should finally sort the activities based on their starting time.  So for example if I had Activity: BreakFast  StartHour: 8  EndHour: 9  and then Activity: Breakfast part 2  StartHour: 8  EndHour: 10   it would print out saying that there is a conflict.

Accessors from Activity Class

- getStartHour()
- getEndHour()

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a function in Activity class called `hasConflict(Activity other)`. In the function check if there is a time conflict. I do not completely agree with how you are keeping time in your activity. You should keep two `Date` called `start` and `end` and use the `getTime()` to see if there is a conflict between two activities. It should be a simple `if statement`.

Second, change your `activities` array to `LinkedList<Activity>`. You keep `MAX_SIZE` of your list and check that before saying that the `database is full`

Third use `Collections.sort()` to sort your activities. There are two ways to call that function.

- Implement Comparable for your `Activity` class and compare the `provided` activity with `this` activity in the function
- Implement `Comparator` and provide an instance of that to this function

Once you have all of the above, you can write your functions to

- First check if there is space in your database by checking `list.size()` with `MAX_SIZE`
- Iterate through the list and see if the new activity has any conflict with any existing one
- If all of above is ok, add the activity to list and sort whenever you want.

There are better ways than sorting as in adding the activity to correct index the first time while you are iterating the activities to check for conflict but this will do for now.

---

Answer (score 0):

Below, is a version using collections, while keeping the total amount and order and uniqueness of elements by using a TreeSet. I didn't include the get/set methods, but it should be straightforward.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.TreeSet;


public class Activity {

    public long startHour;
    public long endHour;

    public static final int MAX_SIZE = 10;

    public static TreeSet<Activity> activities = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Activity>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Activity o1, Activity o2) {
            return Long.compare(o1.startHour, o2.startHour);
        }
    });    

    public boolean intersect(Activity activity) {
        return (activity.startHour >= this.startHour && activity.startHour < this.endHour)
                || (this.startHour >= activity.startHour && this.startHour < activity.endHour);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "start: " + startHour + ", end: " + endHour;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return Objects.hash(startHour, endHour);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (this == object) return true;

        Activity other = (Activity) object;

        return (startHour == other.startHour) && (endHour == other.endHour);
    }

    public static void addActivity(Activity aActivity)
    {
        if (activities.size() >= MAX_SIZE) {
            System.out.println("The activities database is full");
            return;
        }

        for (Activity a : activities) {
            if (a.intersect(aActivity)) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Activity %s intersect with %s", a, aActivity));
                return;
            }
        }
        activities.add(aActivity);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Activity a1 = new Activity();

        a1.startHour = 0;
        a1.endHour = 5;

        Activity b1 = new Activity();

        b1.startHour = 3;
        b1.endHour = 7;

        Activity b2 = new Activity();

        b2.startHour = 5;
        b2.endHour = 9;

        Activity b3 = new Activity();
        b3.startHour = 1;
        b3.endHour = 2;

        addActivity(a1);
        addActivity(b1);
        addActivity(b1);
        addActivity(b2);
        addActivity(b3);

        System.out.println(activities);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not doing it the best possible way. You insert an element at the end of the array and then sort the whole thing. However, you start with an empty array and then activities are added. You should find the place where you can insert the element and shift other elements to the right.

```
public void AddActivity(Activity aActivity)
{
    //Check if activity array is full
    if(activities[activities.length-1] != null)
    {
        System.out.println("The activities database is full");
        return;
    }
    //Find the desired location and the first empty space
    int desiredLocation = -1;
    int firstEmptySpace = -1
    for(int i=0;(i<activities.length) && (firstEmptySpace == -1);i++)
    {
        if ((desiredLocation == -1) && (aActivity.getEndHour() > activities[i].getStartHour()))
        {
            if (aActivity.getStartHour() < activities[i].getEndHour())
            {
                //Intersection :(
                return;
            }
            else 
            {
                desiredLocation = i;
            }
        }
        if(activities[i] == null)
        {
            firstEmptySpace = i;
        }
    }
    //shift things to the right
    for (int i = firstEmptySpace; i > desiredLocation; i--)
    {
        activities[i] = activities[i - 1];
    }
    //Override previous value at desired location
    activities[desiredLocation] = aActivity;
}
```